# PHP deadline notification

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a system that can store documents, those documents are jobs due to specific dates so this system should send an email notification to the admin to notify him/her when a due date for a specific document is near.

Basically i have no problem at all, apart from one single very important point: the notification system should work without user intervention. I can easily trigger php scripts on each page visit but i do not want that. This case would be quite "easy", i would just set a date for each document in the sql row and each time the page is visited a php script would check if the current time is near the time set in the sql row for the document. But this needs the page to be visited.

Suppose my client sets a due date for a document and then never visits the site again, how can it happen that a php scripts automatically fires itself to perform the necessary checks to see if there are due dates in the upcoming days?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should look into cron jobs for this, assuming you have access to the server and can set up tasks

Comment: is it a windows or linux op you are using ? for windows you could do a scheduled a task,. Linux can do a cronjob

Comment: linux, thanks @AlexisPeters, i am using a server that states cronjobs are available just for dedicated hosting and i have a semi-dedicated but still hope to find a way

Comment: @Nicola you can find a web service that will "ping" your script at intervals so it will work as cronjob

Comment: @Sharky, just in time! i had the same idea just a few moments ago and found some sites that do the service, for free it seems...
can't wait to try this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [MySQL Event schedular](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html)?